# extension layout not showing

Tags: layout, extensions, magento-1, layout-update

I have an extension that do layout update to push something to all pages headers.
It worked so far for several clients and versions, but suddenly we got a client that just don't get the layout update.

- We know the extension works because routes we added work.
- We already checked with the client that extension output is not disabled in admin panel.
- The client assured us they did clear cache in admin.
- Its probably not because some full-page cache extensions (like varnish), because we tried accessing the pages with "?aaa=bbb" added to the URL and it still didn't work, and usually full-page caching solutions are URL-based.

**And important point to note**: this client manage two sites/stores on the same server (from the same admin), if that might affect anything...

Anyway... here's our layout xml:

`app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\vendor\core.xml`

```
<!-- Layout updates to inject vendor headers to all pages (include vendor js and page metadata). -->
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
                <block type="vendor_core/injectjs" name="vendor_js" as="vendor_js" template="vendor/injectjs.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And here's the `config.xml` that apply this update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

  <modules>
    <Vendor_Core>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Vendor_Core>
  </modules>

  <global>
<models>
  <vendor_core>
    <class>Vendor_Core_Model</class>
  </vendor_core>
</models>

<helpers>
  <vendor_core>
    <class>Vendor_Core_Helper</class>
  </vendor_core>
</helpers>

<blocks>
  <vendor_core>
    <class>Vendor_Core_Block</class>
  </vendor_core>
</blocks>
  </global>

  <frontend>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <vendor_core>
          <file>vendor/core.xml</file>
        </vendor_core>
      </updates>
    </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Note that the company name was replaced with "vendor", so if you notice any typos there ignore them :)

Any ideas why the layout update might not work or how can I figure it out? I might get like an hour at the client's office to test things, but right now I don't have any access, just the code.

EDIT:

Added the phtml file:

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\vendor\injectjs.phtml`

```
<?php if( $this->isEnabled() ): ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" id="vendor-src" <?php echo $this->getAsyncMode(); ?> src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>"></script>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- Note: Vendor (<?php echo $this->getVersion(); ?>) is temporarily disabled via admin panel. -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you skipped the boring stuff, but it's not that boring.  it's actually important.

Comment: don't see why but added anyway. thanks!

Comment: Well your `<frontend>` tag is not closed.

Comment: it is sorry it was removed when I pasted it in the question. fixed the question, thanks!

Comment: and does your `injectjs` block file exists and is name like this? `Vendor/Core/Block/Injectjs.php` ?

Comment: yes, starting with capital I and all other in lower case

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong I deleted it. What is the content of `app/design/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/page/html/head.phtml` ?

Comment: my phtml file is not where you mentioned, its in a different path. added it to question body. I don't have a head.phtml in my extension.

Comment: @Ness yes but as you're referencing `head` I need you to find out the `head.phtml` file and its content because that's the template that will render your block

Comment: @Raphael - but the way I do it (layout update with reference to 'head') it should append my template into the head tag, regardless of head.phtml file. Am I wrong? (http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/). PS I made another edit to the question, appearantely the client manage two websites/stores from the same admin. Do you think it might be related to the problem?

Comment: @Ness that is right only when you add a JS/CSS to the head, not when it's a block so that's definitely not the case here. Post the content of your `head.phtml` and we find out if that's the issue

Comment: I would but I can't access the client's head.phtml (and I didn't implement head.phtml of my own). If you mean to post my template (eg injectjs.phtml) its already in question body.. so whats the case when adding a block? how is that added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40170/discussion-between-raphael-at-digital-pianism-and-ness).

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue could be that the `page/html/head.phtml` template has been modified and the following line has been removed/modified:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

Try to enable Template Hints under System > Configuration > Developers to find out the path of this template and ensure the line I mentioned has not been deleted.

To ensure that the problem does not come from your block, I suggest you should try adding your block to another block, for instance the `after_body_start` block:

```
    <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="vendor_core/injectjs" name="vendor_js" as="vendor_js" template="vendor/injectjs.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

Comment: So we just got a call from the client, they put one of the folders in the wrong place. what a relief :) I can't accept this solution but I learned from it so have my upvote. Thanks!

Comment: @Ness yeah, awesome glad you worked it out =)